# Intellij git revert a commit

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I was using `Eclipse` and `Egit` for a long time and decided to try `Intellij`.
 So far so good, except one thing...
 I can't find an easy way to revert an old commit from my repo!!!

In Eclipse the standard process was: `Go to Git Workspace -> Click Show History(Right Click Project) -> RIght-Click on the commit I want to revert and press Revert Commit.`

In Intellij I can't find anything equivalent. Tried `VCS -> Show Changes View` but there I can only `cherry pick` a commit. I also played with the revert option under `VCS -> git` but got confused by the `changelist` thing(That may hide the answer, but I don't understand how it works).

I can still revert the commit by issuing `git revert <sha>` from terminal but that's what I was trying to avoid in the first place by using git from Intellij and not pure terminal.

Is there a way to do easily the revert in Intellij?

Comment: I also tried to find this feature several days ago. I think it's just missing. Use external git GUI instead.

Comment: @dimzak About the Changelist abstraction. 
You can think about it like a bunch of Stashes on Git. If you don't like it, just use it the "Default" and you will have no problems.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

If you go to Changelist -> Log, and there select the commit, you've got a change detail in the right panel.
There you can select all and click a button (or right click -> revert selected changes).

Comment: This is what @dimzak is looking for. I just tried it, going to the Git history log and selected the top tree element in the right panel and the "revert" command actually going to create the revert commit for us (uncommited of course).

Comment: To clarify, this feature actually creates and applies a reverse patch.  After reverting selected changes, you can view the changes before commit via *9: Version Control* -> *Local Changes*.

Answer (score 18):

I know of only one way and it's not as good as doing it command line.

First create a reverse patch. Go into the log, choose any commit and select `create patch`, check `reverse patch` and save it anywhere.

Then go into VCS menu and select `apply patch` and choose the file you just saved.

Commit those changes.

Still, I would go with doing it command line. Gives a proper automatic commit message as well.

Comment: Well it worked fine, but it took me like 5 minutes for a revert :D

Comment: Sorry but this looks waaaaay too complicated for a simple revert.

Comment: I agree that it's complicated, I would never do it inside intellij but rather command line. This does however answer the question and I include that it's probably worse than doing it command line.

Answer (score 7):

1. **Select** the commit you like to revert in the **history-log**.
2. From the context-menu select **Create Patch...**
3. Select **Reverse patch** checkbox
4. **Apply** the created patch

Answer (score 2):

I've been looking for that option in Idea 2016.2 and it seems it is no longer there ("revert selected changes"). Instead I was able to do "Reset Current Branch to Here" with "Mized" option, pointing to the latest correct commit. Then I was able to just do the commit again.